# Sending a reply to the recipient of the first message in a Gmail thread using GmailApp or MailApp in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, reply

I am trying to write a code in Google Apps Script to send a reply to the recipient of the first message in a Gmail thread. The thread consists of an email that was previously sent by me to someone else. Initially, I tried using GmailApp but it only sends the reply to the sender (me) by default. Then, I switched to using the Gmail API, which allows me to send the reply to the recipient successfully.

However, I encountered another issue. It seems that the Gmail API only supports plain text body for the reply (according this [source](https://www.gmass.co/blog/gmail-api-html-plain-text-messages/), and I would like to include HTML formatting in the email body, similar to what is possible with GmailApp.

Here's a snippet of the code I'm currently using:

```
var messageId = originalMessage.getHeader("Message-ID");
var data = [
  "MIME-Version: 1.0\n",
  `In-Reply-To: ${messageId}\n`,
  `Subject: Re:${originalMessage.getSubject()}\n`,
  `From: ${senderName} <${senderEmail}>\n`,
  `To: ${recipientEmail}\n\n`,
  emailBody,
].join("");
var draftReplyRequestBody = {
  message: {
    threadId: existingThreadId,
    raw: Utilities.base64Encode(data),
  }
};
var draftReplyResponse = Gmail.Users.Drafts.create(draftReplyRequestBody, "me");
var draftReplyId = draftReplyResponse.id;
var sendReplyParams = { id: draftReplyId };

Gmail.Users.Drafts.send(sendReplyParams, "me");
```

My main question is: Is it possible to modify this code to use GmailApp or MailApp instead of the Gmail API in order to send the reply to the recipient of the first message in the thread, similar to how a reminder email works? Additionally, is there any way to include HTML formatting in the email body using GmailApp or MailApp? Generally, which method is reliable and efficient?  using Gmail API or GmailApp or MailApp?

Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. When I saw your question for the first time, I thought that you wanted to include both the text body and the HTML body in the draft email by modifying your script. But, from the bottom of your question, it seems that you might want to achieve other situations. Can I ask you about the detail of your question? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike First, Thank you for your comment. This is the script in which you helped me to use Gmail API  in my other question. But I encountered another issue with this code. Because it uses Gmail api, it cannot send the body of the email in HTML format and it only sends it as plain text. On the other hand, GmailApp and MailApp are able to use HTML format for the body of the email.  Now, I want to know that is it possible to reply to the first message of the thread  using GmailApp or Mail App? ( a message sent by A to B, and A wants to reply to his email again)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that both the text body and the HTML body can be sent by modifying your request body. If this can be achieved, will your question be resolved? But, I'm not sure that your question has more questions. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes if you could modify the above code in order to send HTML body instead of plain text, the problem is solved.  Because in plain text format, the structure of the paragraph is destroyed and I need to send it in html format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your following reply,

> Yes if you could modify the above code in order to send HTML body instead of plain text, the problem is solved.

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to include both the text body and the HTML body in the draft email using Google Apps Script.

In this case, please modify the value of `data` as follows.

#### From:

```
var data = [
  "MIME-Version: 1.0\n",
  `In-Reply-To: ${messageId}\n`,
  `Subject: Re:${originalMessage.getSubject()}\n`,
  `From: ${senderName} <${senderEmail}>\n`,
  `To: ${recipientEmail}\n\n`,
  emailBody,
].join("");
```

#### To:

```
var htmlBody = "<u><b>sample HTML body</b></u>"; // This is a sample HTML body.
var data = [
  "MIME-Version: 1.0\n",
  `In-Reply-To: ${messageId}\n`,
  `Subject: Re:${originalMessage.getSubject()}\n`,
  `From: ${senderName} <${senderEmail}>\n`,
  `To: ${recipientEmail}\n`,
  "Content-type: multipart/alternative; boundary=sampleBoundary\n\n",
  "--sampleBoundary\n",
  "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n\n",
  emailBody,
  "\n\n--sampleBoundary\n",
  "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n",
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\n\n",
  htmlBody,
  "\n\n--sampleBoundary--",
].join("");
```

By this modification, when the mail client can see the HTML body, the HTML body can be seen. And, when the mail client cannot see the HTML body, the text body can be seen.

If you want to include only the HTML body, how about the following modification?

```
var htmlBody = "<u><b>sample HTML body</b></u>"; // This is a sample HTML body.
var data = [
  "MIME-Version: 1.0\n",
  `In-Reply-To: ${messageId}\n`,
  `Subject: Re:${originalMessage.getSubject()}\n`,
  `From: ${senderName} <${senderEmail}>\n`,
  `To: ${recipientEmail}\n`,
  "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n",
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\n\n",
  htmlBody,
].join("");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are fantastic. Your solution works fine for your defined htmlBody variable. In fact, I recall the value of emailbody variable from a cell content in the google sheet. It has multiple lines of texts and when I used your solution,  the lines are merged  and the recipient receives the email body as a single paragraph. So, how can we preserve the structure of email body as multiple lines of texts and avoid merging them?

Comment: @Hamed Thank you for replying. From `Thanks a lot. You are fantastic. Your solution works fine for your defined htmlBody variable.`, I could understand your issue was resolved.

Comment: @Hamed About your new question of `how can we preserve the structure of email body as multiple lines of texts and avoid merging them?`, I would like to support you. But, tht is a new question, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Sure, I will mark your solution as verified and ask the new issue as another question.  As I asked in the title of this question, do you know that is it possible to implement your solution via GmailApp or MailApp?  I mean replying to a specific message of the thread that previously has been send by me.

Comment: @Hamed Thank you for replying. When I saw your new question, I would like to check it. About `As I asked in the title of this question, do you know that is it possible to implement your solution via GmailApp or MailApp?`, from `Yes if you could modify the above code in order to send HTML body instead of plain text, the problem is solved.`, I proposed the above-modified script. I think that it can be actually achieved. If you want to convert the Gmail API to GmailApp, can you post it as a new question? By this, it will help users including me think of a solution.